# RESTful WebService Client in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, restful-authentication

lets say i have a Restful webservice (for my record-class) on a GlassFish, accessable on

```
http://localhost:8080/MyWS/entities.Records/
```

i want to use this Webservice in PHP to read and write records.

how do i use a RESTful Webservice out of PHP?

how to set the action (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)?

how to set the user/password data in the header (glassfish is parsing the header of the HttpRequest to authentificate a user)?

and how to serialize my PHP Record-Class objects to XML (for sending: PUT, POST, DELETE) and to deserialize XML to Record-Class objects (for reading the glassfish/ws-output) easily? is there a php-builtin-method or do i have to write my own XML-Parser?

thank you

Comment: You can try my RESTFul client. It's basic but useful and easy to use. Support basic and digest authorisation. Also support CI GET type. Get it from my git: https://github.com/corysus/restful_client

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how do i use a RESTful Webservice out of PHP?
>   how to set the action (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)?

You can use CURL for that. Recently I've put a simple class for this. You can check it at my [Github page](https://github.com/radmen/REST-Client)

> how to set the user/password data in the header (glassfish is parsing the header of the HttpRequest to authentificate a user)?

Simply set a header with curl_setopt. See comment [#80271](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#80271)

> is there a php-builtin-method or do i have to write my own XML-Parser?

There're some bultin extensions for that. Maybe some will be useful:

- SimpleXML
- DOM Document